# how to save add or remove classes cookies in my javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cookies

I want to save "active" class and "icon" class in cookies. How to do?

**html**

```
<div class="changeWrap">
        <span class="switch-male"><a href="javascript:"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i> Male</a></span>
        <span class="switch-female"><a href="javascript:" class="active"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i><span> Female</span></a></span>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.active{
    color: red;
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/deqzjefq/2/**

Comment: what do u mean by saving active class & icon class in cookies ? what are u trying to achieve

Comment: i really understand what ur question is. do u want to save active class names like 'switch-female' or the complete span tag to cookies ? if yes can i know why u want that ?

Answer (score 0):

First create you cookie:

```
document.cookie="class=active;gender=male";
```

Then get value of cookie (name 'class')

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Then give id to the anchor tags

```
<div class="changeWrap">
        <span class="switch-male"><a href="javascript:" id='male-anchor'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked"></i> Male</a></span>
        <span class="switch-female"><a href="javascript:" id='female-anchor'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></i><span> Female</span></a></span>
</div>
```

Check cookie gender:

```
var gender = getCookie('gender');

if(gender == 'male'{
    document.getElementsById('male-anchor').setAttribute("class", getCookie('class'));
}
else{
    document.getElementsById('female-anchor').setAttribute("class", getCookie('class'));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k8pbp97k/1/